# Running malicious code on SharePoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, security

We have a SharePoint 2013 intranet portal which user can access from home using their corporate lan ID & password.

Most of the users only have read-only access to the site and they can only change their profile picture by uploading image file.

Is there any way to scan these incoming files to ensure no virus is getting uploaded on the server?

Answer (score 1):

By default SharePoint blocks certain file types like Exe, Dll etc. You can make this configuration from Central Admin web site.

Comment: I have already restricted exe and dll files. And the file types user can upload are jpg, png & gif. But what if the image file is infected? Is there a way to block that

Comment: What you mean by image file is infected? I don't know about any exploits through image files.. Also I don't think it is going to affect your SharePoint farm in any way.